# PHP: Duplicate requests when include php file in div

Tags: php, html, include, request

I've a big problem when click in menu item to load php file in div called **#layouts**, because each click, duplicate requests as see the picture below:

[image: duplicate requests firebug]

I use this:

**dashboard.php**

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Catálogo de... >></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#s1">Perfiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s2">Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s3">Usuarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s4">Marcas,Productos,SubProductos</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#s5">Captura de Póliza</a></li>
    <li><a href="#s6">Levantamiento de Servicio</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="layouts">
    <h1>Seleccione una opción del menú</h2>
</div>
```

**functions.js**

```
$('#navigation li a').click(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
    page = $(this).attr('href');
    if (page == "#s1") {$('#layouts').load("./catperfiles.php");}
        else if (page == "#s2") {$('#layouts').load("./catclientes.php");}
            else if (page == "#s3") {$('#layouts').load("./catusuarios.php");}
                else if (page == "#s4") {$('#layouts').load("./catorganizacion.php");}
                    else if (page == "#s5") {$('#layouts').load("./poliza.php");}
                        else if (page == "#s6") {$('#layouts').load("./servicio.php");}

/*$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./"+layout+".php",
    success: function(html) {
        $('#layouts').html(html);
        $('#loading').hide();
   }
});*/

});
```

**servicio.php**

```
<?php include 'config.php' ?>
<h1>Levantamiento del servicio</h1>
<h3>Elija una opción:</h3>
<input id="clientexist" name="typeclient" value="ce" type="radio" />
<label for="clientexist">Cliente existente</label>

<input id="clientnew" name="typeclient" value="cn" type="radio"/>
<label for="clientnew">Cliente nuevo</label>

<div id="areaTypeClient"></div>
```

**config.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The strange thing is that in the php page that does not have this line in the header

```
<?php include 'config.php' ?>
```

this is not the duplication of requests.

If you have a better idea for this type of navigation including the php files in the div, I would like the share. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ajax calls output your javascript with every request, which in turn attaches a new additional click handler every time, thus exponentially incrementing the number of requests per click. Probably your javascript code or files are referenced somewhere in your config.php file.

Solution: Do not include the same javascript code with every ajax call. Or alternatively, this will make sure only one click handler is being processed:

```
$('#navigation li a').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
    page = $(this).attr('href');
    if (page == "#s1") {$('#layouts').load("./catperfiles.php");}
        else if (page == "#s2") {$('#layouts').load("./catclientes.php");}
            else if (page == "#s3") {$('#layouts').load("./catusuarios.php");}
                else if (page == "#s4") {$('#layouts').load("./catorganizacion.php");}
                    else if (page == "#s5") {$('#layouts').load("./poliza.php");}
                        else if (page == "#s6") {$('#layouts').load("./servicio.php");}

});
```

Comment: What not to include the javascript file in each php file, I have to do for this reason: In the file dashboard.php in the head I put this <head>
<php include 'config.php'?>
<title> Service panel </ title>
</ head>, then with that already included the css and js but when you load the php file in the div # layouts, css and functions.js does not recognize and for that reason I had to include at every php file line <php include 'config.php'?>, or you have another idea for this?

Comment: Just use the code I posted in your functions.js then, instead of the one you have, and it will work.

Comment: Sorry forget to comment on your answer, using. Unbind ('click'). are no longer duplicated requests, now add 1 for each click on the menu, ie before it to 1, 2, 4.8, etc and now is 1,2,3,4,5,6 ...